# Oracle: restrict user access to rows where rowdata = USER

Tags: oracle, user-permissions

is there another way to do this? I want to restrict the user to his own module and associated results. First intention was to create a view because this gives the possibility to use a WHERE clause in combination with USER which givs me the username of the connected user.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "ADMIN_STUDENT"."MODULE_LEADER" ("MCODE", "MLECTURER") 
AS   
SELECT "MCODE",
"MLECTURER"     
FROM MODULE   
WHERE MLECTURER = USER;
```

Comment: Why does that view deliver the output you want?

Comment: because i can compare the row data of MLECTURER with the current connected USER. The user should only see "his" data in the table.

EDIT: Can these be achieved as part of user management via OEM ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check out Oracle Virtual Private Database or Oracle Label Security](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_securing_data.htm)

Comment: +1  It is a valid alternative, but I would avoid VPD as much as possible.  It is very frustrating when you ask Oracle for query X and it secretly replaces your query with Y.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, add use `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')` in the view definition.